# Windows 8, Gestures, .Net/WPF

Tags: windows, touch

So Windows 8 has new way to handle gestures (GestureRecognizer for Metro / InteractionContext for Win32).

- What is the sanctioned way to go for a .Net/WPF desktop application? Interop with InteractionContext?
- Does .Net 4.5 WPF API use the improvements in Windows 8 when running on it? If not, what are the differences?

Thanks!